# Is there a command or technique to 'concreteify' symlinks? (Copy the files so they're no longer a symlink)

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage a multipackage monorepo.

It works well in my development environment, where I can be working on multiple packages that have dependencies on each other and the code keeps working.

However, I'm running into some trouble building this code for production.

Essentially, the problem is, when I compile my code, I'll get some cjs modules that have

```
   require('some-dependency')
```

The dependency will exist as a symlink in the `node_modules` folder, and so works in my development environment.

However, if I'm wanting to copy node_modules onto a docker image, this won't work, as Docker just ignores symlinks.

What I would like to do, is have a command that inspects `node_modules` for symlinks, and if they exist, then just copy all the files to be concrete files.

Is this possible? What is the terminology?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using hardlinks in your case?

Comment: Are hardlinks a specific thing? Lerna creates the symlinks for you.

Comment: A symlink just points to the other location (a file name), a hardlink points to the data on the drive itself. So deleting a file means deleting all hardlinks until the disk space is set free, while symlinks are just disabled once the target they point at is gone. On the other hand symlinks can be relative (like two dirs down, one up). @Eric Mintz' use of `cp -L` however seems simpler than replacing all symlinks by hardlinks.

Comment: Does this fit your needs?: https://github.com/Venryx/file-syncer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add the dereference option to the cp command. Dereference will cause cp to copy the linked file rather than the simlink.

```
cp --dereference --recursive node_modules/* dest_dir/
```

And alternatively:

```
cp -L -r node_modules/* dest_dir/
```

Comment: Would it be possible to copy from and to the same directory?

Comment: cp to a temp directory, then move the files back and overwrite the links.

Comment: Fantastic, this works!